# Shortest area bisecting line in a convex polygon

Tags: algorithm

I have troubles finding this:

[image: Shortest Bisecting line picture]

I don't know how to find this or even write algorithm to do this. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you Elaborate your question more? tell people you want help in which programming language? add its tag in question and kindly read Question Guideline for Stack overflow!

Comment: Well what I want is to find the shortest bisecting line in a convex polygon. I don't mind any language, I just want to know how to do this theoretically. I want that line to be the shortest to bisect it in 2 halves(of area)

Comment: The question would be clearer as "shortest area bisecting line in a convex polygon".

Comment: @KronwarsCZ Edit your question and add this information

Comment: @Georgy or MathOverflow. This is a geometry problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

I would tackle this as follows:

- study the problem in a quadrilateral and establish the rule that relates the position of a point on an edge and the length of the segment that will halve the area, or more generally split in two specified parts.
- find the condition that gives the shortest line.
- generalize to a point on an edge of a general polygon.

I am fairly sure that for a point moving on an edge, the minimal configurations occur in a finite number, and by scanning all edges you can enumerate all the candidates and find the shortest.